# Encrypt SQLite DB, access trough Symfony, open with password

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, encryption, doctrine

I am trying to make a tool that deal with quite sensitive data, with PHP/Symfony, ut password protected should be sufficient.

I would like users to submit the password that open the DB.

I would like a SQLite DB in order to make it run locally on a very small hardware and also with a good data portability (just copy&paste the directory, relauch server, done).

How to open DB after a password submission ? How to do that across Doctrine ORM ?
Does a magic plugin with theses functions exists ?

(I'm also considering an encryption row by row, but I would like to know if there is a more standard way)

Answer (score 1):

You could encrypt the database file with gpg and decrypt before opening the connections

Comment: Where would you hook to code before and after doctrine connection ? A service replacement for doctrine and encapsuling everything ?